# Comparing Similar Text Strings in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I am currently trying to reconcile “Name” fields from two separate data sources.  I have a number of names that are not an exact match but are close enough to be considered matched (examples below).   Do you have any ideas of how I can improve the number of automated matches?    I am already eliminating middle initials from the match criteria.

[image]

Current Match Formula:

```
=IFERROR(IF(LEFT(SYSTEM A,IF(ISERROR(SEARCH(" ",SYSTEM A)),LEN(SYSTEM A),SEARCH(" ",SYSTEM A)-1))=LEFT(SYSTEM B,IF(ISERROR(SEARCH(" ",SYSTEM B)),LEN(SYSTEM B),SEARCH(" ",SYSTEM B)-1)),"",IF(LEFT(SYSTEM A,FIND(",",SYSTEM A))=LEFT(SYSTEM B,FIND(",",SYSTEM B)),"Last Name Match","RESEARCH")),"RESEARCH")
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You might consider using the [Microsoft Fuzzy Lookup Addin](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15011).

From MS site:

> Overview
>
> The Fuzzy Lookup Add-In for Excel was developed by Microsoft Research and performs fuzzy matching of textual data in Microsoft Excel. It can be used to identify fuzzy duplicate rows within a single table or to fuzzy join similar rows between two different tables. The matching is robust to a wide variety of errors including spelling mistakes, abbreviations, synonyms and added/missing data. For instance, it might detect that the rows “Mr. Andrew Hill”, “Hill, Andrew R.” and “Andy Hill” all refer to the same underlying entity, returning a similarity score along with each match. While the default configuration works well for a wide variety of textual data, such as product names or customer addresses, the matching may also be customized for specific domains or languages.

Comment: I can't install the addon in office due to administrator priviliges required, due to .net framework required. :-(

Comment: This is great, but I can't get it to produce more than 10 rows. I've clicked through the config without success. Any tips?

Answer (score 6):

I would look into using [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypocorism) list (English section only) to help weed out the common shortenings.

Addition, you might want to consider using a function that will tell you, in exact terms, how "close" two string are. The following code came from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4243036/levenshtein-distance-in-excel) and thanks to [smirkingman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/338101/smirkingman).

```vb
Option Explicit
Public Function Levenshtein(s1 As String, s2 As String)

Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim l1 As Integer
Dim l2 As Integer
Dim d() As Integer
Dim min1 As Integer
Dim min2 As Integer

l1 = Len(s1)
l2 = Len(s2)
ReDim d(l1, l2)
For i = 0 To l1
    d(i, 0) = i
Next
For j = 0 To l2
    d(0, j) = j
Next
For i = 1 To l1
    For j = 1 To l2
        If Mid(s1, i, 1) = Mid(s2, j, 1) Then
            d(i, j) = d(i - 1, j - 1)
        Else
            min1 = d(i - 1, j) + 1
            min2 = d(i, j - 1) + 1
            If min2 < min1 Then
                min1 = min2
            End If
            min2 = d(i - 1, j - 1) + 1
            If min2 < min1 Then
                min1 = min2
            End If
            d(i, j) = min1
        End If
    Next
Next
Levenshtein = d(l1, l2)
End Function
```

What this will do is tell you how many insertions and deletions one must do to one string to get to the other. I would try to keep this number low (and last names should be exact).

Answer (score 5):

I have a (long) formula that you can use. It's not as well honed as those above – and only works for surname, rather than a full name –
but you might find it useful.

So if you have a header row and want to compare `A2` with `B2`, place this in any other cell on that row (e.g., `C2`) and copy down to the end.

> =IF(A2=B2,"EXACT",IF(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"-"," ")=SUBSTITUTE(B2,"-"," "),"Hyphen",IF(LEN(A2)>LEN(B2),IF(LEN(A2)>LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,B2,"")),"Whole String",IF(MID(A2,1,1)=MID(B2,1,1),1,0)+IF(MID(A2,2,1)=MID(B2,2,1),1,0)+IF(MID(A2,3,1)=MID(B2,3,1),1,0)+IF(MID(A2,LEN(A2),1)=MID(B2,LEN(B2),1),1,0)+IF(MID(A2,LEN(A2)-1,1)=MID(B2,LEN(B2)-1,1),1,0)+IF(MID(A2,LEN(A2)-2,1)=MID(B2,LEN(B2)-2,1),1,0)&"°"),IF(LEN(B2)>LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B2,A2,"")),"Whole String",IF(MID(A2,1,1)=MID(B2,1,1),1,0)+IF(MID(A2,2,1)=MID(B2,2,1),1,0)+IF(MID(A2,3,1)=MID(B2,3,1),1,0)+IF(MID(A2,LEN(A2),1)=MID(B2,LEN(B2),1),1,0)+IF(MID(A2,LEN(A2)-1,1)=MID(B2,LEN(B2)-1,1),1,0)+IF(MID(A2,LEN(A2)-2,1)=MID(B2,LEN(B2)-2,1),1,0)&"°"))))

This will return:

- **EXACT** – if it's an exact match
- **Hyphen** – if it's a pair of double-barrelled names but on has a hyphen and the other a space
- **Whole string** – if all of one surname is part of the other
  (e.g., if a Smith has become a French-Smith)

After that it will give you a degree from 0° to 6° depending on the number of points of comparison between the two. (i.e., 6° compares better).

As I say a bit rough and ready, but hopefully gets you in roughly the right ball-park.

Comment: This is so undervalued at all levels. Very nicely done! Do you by any chance have any updates to this?

Answer (score 2):

Was searching for something similar. I found the code below. I hope this helps to next user who comes to this question

> Returns 91% for Abracadabra / Abrakadabra, 75% for Hollywood Street/Hollyhood Str, 62% for Florence/France and 0 for Disneyland

I'd say it's close enough to what you wanted :)

```vb
Public Function Similarity(ByVal String1 As String, _
    ByVal String2 As String, _
    Optional ByRef RetMatch As String, _
    Optional min_match = 1) As Single
Dim b1() As Byte, b2() As Byte
Dim lngLen1 As Long, lngLen2 As Long
Dim lngResult As Long

If UCase(String1) = UCase(String2) Then
    Similarity = 1
Else:
    lngLen1 = Len(String1)
    lngLen2 = Len(String2)
    If (lngLen1 = 0) Or (lngLen2 = 0) Then
        Similarity = 0
    Else:
        b1() = StrConv(UCase(String1), vbFromUnicode)
        b2() = StrConv(UCase(String2), vbFromUnicode)
        lngResult = Similarity_sub(0, lngLen1 - 1, _
        0, lngLen2 - 1, _
        b1, b2, _
        String1, _
        RetMatch, _
        min_match)
        Erase b1
        Erase b2
        If lngLen1 >= lngLen2 Then
            Similarity = lngResult / lngLen1
        Else
            Similarity = lngResult / lngLen2
        End If
    End If
End If

End Function

Private Function Similarity_sub(ByVal start1 As Long, ByVal end1 As Long, _
                                ByVal start2 As Long, ByVal end2 As Long, _
                                ByRef b1() As Byte, ByRef b2() As Byte, _
                                ByVal FirstString As String, _
                                ByRef RetMatch As String, _
                                ByVal min_match As Long, _
                                Optional recur_level As Integer = 0) As Long
'* CALLED BY: Similarity *(RECURSIVE)

Dim lngCurr1 As Long, lngCurr2 As Long
Dim lngMatchAt1 As Long, lngMatchAt2 As Long
Dim I As Long
Dim lngLongestMatch As Long, lngLocalLongestMatch As Long
Dim strRetMatch1 As String, strRetMatch2 As String

If (start1 > end1) Or (start1 < 0) Or (end1 - start1 + 1 < min_match) _
Or (start2 > end2) Or (start2 < 0) Or (end2 - start2 + 1 < min_match) Then
    Exit Function '(exit if start/end is out of string, or length is too short)
End If

For lngCurr1 = start1 To end1
    For lngCurr2 = start2 To end2
        I = 0
        Do Until b1(lngCurr1 + I) <> b2(lngCurr2 + I)
            I = I + 1
            If I > lngLongestMatch Then
                lngMatchAt1 = lngCurr1
                lngMatchAt2 = lngCurr2
                lngLongestMatch = I
            End If
            If (lngCurr1 + I) > end1 Or (lngCurr2 + I) > end2 Then Exit Do
        Loop
    Next lngCurr2
Next lngCurr1

If lngLongestMatch < min_match Then Exit Function

lngLocalLongestMatch = lngLongestMatch
RetMatch = ""

lngLongestMatch = lngLongestMatch _
+ Similarity_sub(start1, lngMatchAt1 - 1, _
start2, lngMatchAt2 - 1, _
b1, b2, _
FirstString, _
strRetMatch1, _
min_match, _
recur_level + 1)
If strRetMatch1 <> "" Then
    RetMatch = RetMatch & strRetMatch1 & "*"
Else
    RetMatch = RetMatch & IIf(recur_level = 0 _
    And lngLocalLongestMatch > 0 _
    And (lngMatchAt1 > 1 Or lngMatchAt2 > 1) _
    , "*", "")
End If


RetMatch = RetMatch & Mid$(FirstString, lngMatchAt1 + 1, lngLocalLongestMatch)


lngLongestMatch = lngLongestMatch _
+ Similarity_sub(lngMatchAt1 + lngLocalLongestMatch, end1, _
lngMatchAt2 + lngLocalLongestMatch, end2, _
b1, b2, _
FirstString, _
strRetMatch2, _
min_match, _
recur_level + 1)

If strRetMatch2 <> "" Then
    RetMatch = RetMatch & "*" & strRetMatch2
Else
    RetMatch = RetMatch & IIf(recur_level = 0 _
    And lngLocalLongestMatch > 0 _
    And ((lngMatchAt1 + lngLocalLongestMatch < end1) _
    Or (lngMatchAt2 + lngLocalLongestMatch < end2)) _
    , "*", "")
End If

Similarity_sub = lngLongestMatch

End Function
```

Comment: you're copying the code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42657518/995714) without giving any credits

Answer (score 1):

You can use the similarity function (pwrSIMILARITY) to compare the strings and get a percentage match of the two. You can make it case-sensitive or not. You'll need to decide what percentage of a match is "close enough" for your needs.

There a reference page at http://officepowerups.com/help-support/excel-function-reference/excel-text-analyzer/pwrsimilarity/.

But it works pretty well for comparing text in column A against column B.

Answer (score 1):

This code scan column a and column b, if it finds any similarity in both columns it shows in yellow. You can use color filter to get the final value. I have not added that part into code.

```vb
Sub item_difference()

Range("A1").Select

last_row_all = Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
last_row_new = Range("B65536").End(xlUp).Row

Range("A1:B" & last_row_new).Select
With Selection.Interior
    .Pattern = xlSolid
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 65535
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With

For i = 1 To last_row_new
For j = 1 To last_row_all

If Range("A" & i).Value = Range("A" & j).Value Then

Range("A" & i & ":B" & i).Select
With Selection.Interior
    .Pattern = xlSolid
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
    .TintAndShade = 0
  .PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With

End If
Next j
Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Although my solution does not allow identifying very different strings, it is useful for partial match (substring match), e.g. "this is a string" and "a string" will result as "matching":

**just add "*" before and after the string to look for into the table.**

Usual formula:

- vlookup(A1,B1:B10,1,0)
- cerca.vert(A1;B1:B10;1;0)

becomes

- vlookup("*" & A1 & "*",B1:B10;1,0)
- cerca.vert("*" & A1 & "*";B1:B10;1;0)

"&" is the "short version" for **concatenate()**