# Conditional Formatting: 3 color scale showing text relevance in Excel for Mac

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, conditional-formatting

Is there a way to use conditional formatting in the following manner in Excel? (For those who are curious, I am using Excel 2010 for Mac)

I want Cell B2 to be green when A2 says "John likes green apples" and B2 also says "John likes green apples", yellow if A2 says "John likes green apples" and B2 says "Bill likes blue apples", and red if A2 says "John likes green apples" and B2 says "Bill hates red oranges".

I am just wondering if there is a way to something to that effect.

Thanks

Comment: Just to be clear, the metric is the number/percentage of words in `B2` that are found in `A2`?

Comment: Anything like a percentage works. It doesn't need to be exact, I just need something relative.

Comment: Would VBa be acceptable or do you only want to do this with conditional formatting

Comment: As requested by @slhck I've deleted my answer that outlined how to achieve this on a PC, and posted a question and answer here to address the PC case in particular: http://superuser.com/questions/753869/excel-conditional-formatting-3-color-scale-scoring-fuzzy-matched-data

Comment: VBA is acceptable. I wasn't aware that was an option, it's the result I care about. Thanks @DaveRook

Answer (score 2):

Sure. Select cell B2 and go to
**Home** tab > **Styles** group > **Conditional Formatting** > **New Rule** > **Use formula to determine which cells to format**

Enter this formula:

```
=AND(A2="John likes green apples",B2="John likes green apples")
```

Set the set the format to fill green.

Repeat for each additional color and rule.

Comment: So my thing is that I have a couple thousand rows, each with different text in A and B, I was hoping the conditional formatting would help me identify which sets were more alike, and I don't want to have to go one by one. Any suggestions? I appreciate the reply.

Comment: It sounds like you may want [Fuzzy Lookup](http://superuser.com/a/437398/311091).

Comment: Note where I say I am using Excel 2010 for Mac, I was so hoping that would work but it looks like I would need a PC.

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize it was Windows only. You should be able to use a fuzzy comparison implemented in VBA. I haven't tried it, but [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4660525/3211023) looks promising.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is also not totally clear. Does the actual name matter (John, Bill)? Will the fruit matter? Or is about 3 conditions

1. Names match and feelings towards the fruit match
2. Names don't match but feelings towards the fruit match
3. Names don't match and feelings towards the fruit don't match

I've assumed that the only thing that matters are the persons name, and if they have the same feeling towards something. Therefore, the persons name can be anything and if both Bill and Claire hate the fruit, I have assumed that is also an orange. You have the code now, so it should be easy to amend!

```
Sub Button1_Click()

Dim row As Integer
row = 1
Do While (True)

If Range("A" & row).Value = "" Then
    Exit Do
End If

Dim score As Integer
score = 0

Dim wordsA() As String
wordsA = Split(Range("A" & row).Value, " ")

Dim wordsB() As String
wordsB = Split(Range("B" & row).Value, " ")

If wordsA(0) = wordsB(0) Then
    score = score + 1
End If

If wordsA(1) = wordsB(1) Then
    score = score + 1
Else
    score = score + 3
End If


'2 = both same name, both feel same way
'1 = different name, both feel same way
'3 = differet feelings

Select Case score
   Case 1
   Case 4
Range("B" & row).Interior.ColorIndex = 46

   Case 2
   Range("B" & row).Interior.ColorIndex = 43

   Case 3
Range("B" & row).Interior.ColorIndex = 30


End Select

row = row + 1

Loop

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Oh so I just assumed conditional formatting would have a way so for me, any solution works. Ok forgive me for being novice, I have plugged the code into Visual Basic Editor but I don't know where to go from there to get it to run.. any guidance would be great. Thanks!

Comment: Well, to test it, first create a COPY of the excel file!!! Then, on the copy, just click the Play (green arrow) button to first see if it does what you want (or not) @user1470242

Comment: Where does the play button show up on Excel for Mac? I am not seeing it. #novicequestion2

Comment: I go to Tools > Macro > Macros and then hit Run but nothing happens.

Comment: hmmm... do you have macros enabled? I don't know Mac at all, all I know is Excel-Mac can run macros hence the post. As to HOW you execute it, I think you'd be best doing a Google search, I don't think I can help much with that... Sorry @user1470242

Comment: Ok I am just getting a "subscript out of range" error

Comment: @user1470242 on what line ?

Comment: The one that says If wordsA(1) = wordsB(1) Then

Comment: Well, does every cell in column A and B have at least 2 words in, as per your original example? @user1470242

Comment: I believe there are some with less. It's about 20,000 rows from an exported report.

Comment: In that case, the detail you've provided in the original post is meaningless is it not? You have requested information on how to work with data in a given format, and you've had 4 answers (1 has been deleted) and now, are you really saying that the detail you've given is only partly accurate?

Answer (score 0):

This would definitely require VBA. The following function will return a value from 0-1 (i.e. a percentage) of values that match **in the same position**.  Use this the same as you would use a built-in function.  You could then apply normal conditional formatting to this value.

It has an optional True/False (default false) of whether it should be case-sensitive.

"Bob ate Dinner" vs "Bob ate Dinner." would be 0.66, as it does not ignore punctuation.

"Bob Bob Bob Bob" vs "Bob Bob" = 2/4 = 0.5--when strings contain different number of words, the bigger of the two is the denominator, but your numerator maxes out at the smaller of the two.

```
Function ScorePair(stringInput As String, stringTarget As String, Optional caseSensitive As Boolean = False) As Double

Dim scoreNum As Integer
Dim scoreDen As Integer
Dim splitInput As Variant
Dim splitTarget As Variant
Dim theScore As Double
Dim sizeTarget As Integer
Dim sizeInput As Integer
Dim loopSize As Integer

'Initialize
scoreNum = 0
i = 0

'Extract strings into arrays of words
splitInput = Split(stringInput, " ")
splitTarget = Split(stringTarget, " ")

'Get sizes of arrays to know how much to loop (smaller of two) and what to set denominator at (bigger of two)
sizeInput = UBound(splitInput, 1)
sizeTarget = UBound(splitTarget, 1)
scoreDen = WorksheetFunction.Max(sizeTarget, sizeInput) + 1
loopSize = WorksheetFunction.Min(sizeTarget, sizeInput)

'Loop through arrays comparing them by matching position
For i = i To loopSize
    If caseSensitive Then
        If splitInput(i) = splitTarget(i) Then
            scoreNum = scoreNum + 1
        End If
    ElseIf LCase(splitInput(i)) = LCase(splitTarget(i)) Then
        scoreNum = scoreNum + 1
    End If
Next

'Calculate the score as percentage
theScore = scoreNum / scoreDen
ScorePair = theScore

End Function
```

Comment: Forgive the novice question but once I plug that into Visual Basic Editor, what do I do?
Thanks

Comment: You place the code into a module.  In a cell type '=scorepair(a1,a2)'

Comment: This one is doing ok but I don't care so much for the placement of the word.

Comment: So, would you like it to work the same as it does, except without having to be the same position?  So "Bob Ate A Cow" = "A Cow Ate Bob"?