# Formula to compare string differences

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I am trying to get the difference between the content of two different cells. For example:

```
         A           B             C (Result of formula)
1   ABCDE        ABCDEFGH         FGH
2   ABCDEFGH     ABCFGH           DE
3   AB 123 CDE   CDE 345 AB       345
```

Can anyone recommend how I can achieve this?

Comment: In the past I've used text manipulation utilities to handle this sort of processing.  My preference is awk, but PERL would do a good job too.  Either could do it in under 50 lines of code but I don't have any idea of how to approach the problem with Excel.

Comment: You should take a look at this question, the answer may head you in the right direction - [Comparing Similar Text Strings in Excel](http://superuser.com/q/437387/97028).

Answer (score 0):

> By using the following formula, you can achieve just that:
>
> =SUBSTITUTE(B1,A1,"")

That would compare the contents of cell A1 and B1 and return the difference, as asked.
Answer is by Jacob Jan Tuinstra taken from here: [Compare 2 text cells and show difference in the third cell](https://superuser.com/questions/518214/compare-2-text-cells-and-show-difference-in-the-third-cell)