# How to check if a table contains a text string in any cell

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have two long lists of names, and I'm trying to see where the differences in the lists are i.e. are there extra people in one list, and if so who.

I'm thinking that a good way to do this would be to use the match function, and then you can see where there are any errors, and hence the differences in the list.

My problem is a name in one list is not the same as it is in the other list, for example in one list we have Bob Mortimer, and in the other list we gave Mr Bob J Mortimer. I tried to get around this by using wildcards, but it didn't seem to work and I just kept getting `#N/A`

The formula I used is `=MATCH("*"&F9&"*"&G9&"*",ListPersonnel!$E$9:$E$1287,0)` where F9 and G9 are first name and last name respectively

I also tried the search function `=SEARCH("*"&B3&"*"&C3&"*",ListPersonnel!$E$9:$E$1287)`, but again, to no avail.

I'm fairly certain I'm using these forumlas wrong, but I'm unsure how I can use either correctly

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: are the lookup names also in two columns, first and last?

Comment: There are proposed solutions here: https://superuser.com/questions/437387/comparing-similar-text-strings-in-excel

Comment: lookup names are not, they're all one string

Comment: Then why are you looking in two columns?

Comment: Apologies - that was a mistake. Looking up straight down the E column.

Comment: then your match should work now.

Answer (score -1):

Simply, you are trying to find Duplicate Name between two columns. But to execute the formula to produce accurate result, you need to work with basics other wise no formula could deliver 100%.

Like, you have to make pattern. Name start with Title like Mr. or MR or Ms., white space between Title, First & Last Name, also like Name start with Last or First name.

Check the screen shot below, I've used three simple formula to determine Match or No Match or Duplicate name.

[image]

```
=IF(EXACT(A2, B2), "Duplicate", "No Match")

=IF(COUNTIF($A2:$B20, $A2)>1, "Full match", "No Match")

=IF(COUNTIF($B2:$B20, $A2)=0, "No match in B", "Match in B")
```

Comment: There is a **lot** wrong with this answer.  First, if you would carefully read the comments to the question, you'd see that the OP had a minor mistake in the formula he was using.  Scott pointed it out and presumably OP's problem is solved.  That makes this answer *entirely unnecessary*, even if if was a valid solution to the OP's question, which it is not.

Comment: Yeah, I've seen comments also,, I thought better suggest some easier one. You have raised a good point. :-)